# Robustness to noise of a parametric oscillator

Tags: anharmonic-oscillators

I'm an experimentalist working with trapped nanoparticles with optical dipole trap experiments. In the experiment, surprisingly I observed that if I periodically modulate (at full depth) the trap intensity at a frequency much larger than the radial trap frequency of the particle, then surprisingly, I can see an extended dark lifetime (no photon scattering) of the particle in the trap (asymptotically approaching the vacuum lifetime) compared with the lifetime where I leave the particle in the static trap. My intuition for why this happens is related to the nonlinearity of the dipole trap but don't have a good way to understand the effect analytically. Are there any insights on why this could happen?